# Download Readablestream as file

Tags: javascript

I am getting a readable stream from my api.how can i convert the whole readable stream to createObject URL so that i can download the file.

```
// res.body is a readable stream
  // const reader = res.body.getReader()
  // console.log(reader)
  const contentDisposition = res.headers.get("content-disposition")
  const contentType = res.headers.get("content-type")
  const filename = contentDisposition.match(/filename="(.+)"/)[1]
  const file = new Blob([res.body], { type: contentType }) // this is not working
  const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file)

  const a = document.createElement("a")
  document.body.appendChild(a)
  a.style = "display: none"
  a.href = objectUrl
  a.download = filename
  a.click()
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved this using this code

```
.then((response) => response.blob())
.then((blob) => URL.createObjectURL(blob))
.then((href) => {
  const a = document.createElement("a")
  document.body.appendChild(a)
  a.style = "display: none"
  a.href = href
  a.download = fileName
  a.click()
})
```

Comment: This code makes no sense... You can remove the whole ReadbleStream part if you're not gonna consume it as a stream. Simply do `.then((response) => response.blob())` from the beginning. It's like doing `str1 = "hello";
str2 = str1.split( "" ).map( c => String.fromCharCode( c.charCodeAt(0) ) ).concat( " world".split( "" ) ).join( "" )` instead of `str2 = str1 + " world"`

Comment: Why wouldn't it?

Comment: Not sure.i tried many alternatives and endedup with the above answer

Comment: There is no reason you'd be able to consume this Body as a ReadableStream and not as a Blob directly. You certainly did something wrong when you tried.

Comment: I don't know why this works either, but it saved me big time! Thank you!

Comment: Note that the call to `URL.createObjectURL(blob)` effectively makes an in-memory byte array. Therefore, this solution is not appropriate for attempting to download large files, like 2 GB.

Comment: You know @Kevin I have been looking for a better replacement ever since `BlobBuilder` was deprecated. My main question today is how do I run video streams if I have a Stream API from which I can fetch data using the `Fetch` API.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon, if you're talking about trying to stream video and play it in the browser at the same time, like YouTube, then I'm not sure, other than just having a link to an .mp4 file. If on the other hand, you are talking about downloading the data from the Stream API to a file, then I do have a couple potential solutions. They work around the memory problem I was referring to in my previous comment. But again, this is for downloading/saving the data from the API to a file. I'm not exactly sure what your "Stream API" looks like. If that is what you need, I can see about giving you more.

Comment: @Kevin the first one. I assume that If I have free control over the bytes coming from the `ReadableStream` such that I can plug that into a `HTMLVideoElement.srcObject` then the implementation is straight forward. But it takes a `MediaStream()` instead. How can I reconcile the two? YouTube actually isn’t the only application that I know has implemented this feature. I know applications from over ten years ago that implemented this but I didn’t understand how they did it.

Comment: Hmm, sorry @ChukwujiobiCanon. My solution simply causes the browser to invoke its native file download functionality, straight to disk. While it does utilize the Fetch API `Request` and `Response`, I am not familiar with the `MediaStream` that you mentioned.